# Where can i implement a php code in joomla?

Tags: php, html, joomla

So I'm doing this website with Joomla and I don't have much experience with Joomla.
I just want to get the values of some checkboxes and print them into a text area.
I have the script already, I just need to implement it.

Here the raw Html code of the checkboxes:

```
<div class="checkboxShop">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxShopInput" name="shop" />
        <label for="checkboxShopInput"></label>
    </form>
</div>
```

And Here is the raw Html code of the submit button:

```
<form action="/Flex/index.php/shop" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Buy">
</form>
```

All I want is to get all the values of the checkboxes and add them to a textarea in index.php/shop. I wrote this code to get the values but i don't know where to add this:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['shop'])) {
    foreach($_POST['shop'] as $check) {
            echo $check; //echoes the value set in the HTML form for each checked checkbox.
                         //so, if I were to check 1, 3, and 5 it would echo value 1, value 3, value 5.
                         //in your case, it would echo whatever $row['Report ID'] is equivalent to.

            echo "<input type='text' name='message' value='" . $check . "'>"
    }
}
?>
```

I've read that i need this but I'm not sure how: `<?php include "name_of_script.php";?>`

Thanks for the help

Comment: Joomla has its own stack exchange here https://joomla.stackexchange.com  where you'll get better joomla answers.

Comment: That being said you may need to provide some background on what you have already - ie whether you are dealing with an existing module or component, and whether you are dealing with an existing request-response, need to persist the data, etc. Also... why is your submit button in a separate form from the fields you intend to submit?  Also... if you have index.php in your urls then you should rename your htaccess.txt file to .htaccess at the root of your site and turn on sef urls in the config.

Comment: This question was answered here: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/20601/where-can-i-implement-a-php-code-in-joomla

Comment: @itoctopus yeah I know, that's me. anyway thanks:)